# Application.ScreenUpdating = True from immediate

Tags: excel, vba

I used to be able to set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` from the immediate window after a macro crashed.  Now it just returns `True` or `False`.  Can anyone help?

PS, sorry if this has been asked before.  I really did look but only found stuff for others with much different problems.

Comment: Do you accidentally put `?` in front of it?

Comment: Maybe time to look at proper error handling.

Comment: @GSerg I did, thanks.